# Is it possible to scrape data out of the actual file (Preview) of a network request rather than Headers using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am essentially just trying to grab the code from a script file and store it rather than scraping the data from the header. How could I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by `scraping the data from the header`

Comment: @Bravo if you inspect a webpage then go to Network > Headers. I have managed to scrape that data but want to get some data from Network > Preview instead.

Comment: that would be the body of the response that you are looking for

Comment: @Bravo Ok, so right now I am just logging response but what should it be instead?

Comment: scrapping it? I dunno your code is a mystery wrapped in an enigma

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Bravo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469442/how-can-i-log-the-body-of-the-response-of-a-network-request-using-puppeteer